# update association's attribute with after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two model here, **Order** and **Return**

When a **Return** is refunded I would like to update the **Order** `:status` to "refunded"

return.rb

```
belongs_to :order
after_save :set_order_status

enum status: { pending: 0, confirmed: 1, refunded: 2 }

def set_order_status 
  if self.status == "refunded"
     self.order.status = "refunded"
  end
end
```

order.rb

```
 has_one    :returning

  enum status: { pending: 0, paid: 1, confirmed: 2 , shipped: 3, cancelled: 4, refunded: 5 }
```

I believe it doesn't work this way... my method `set_order_status` doesn't change anything to the order...

Comment: Have you tried saving the order directly instead? like `self.order.save`

Comment: yes it did not do the job, but Vishal answers does :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have methods with enum. so you can do like below in after_save method,

return.rb

```
belongs_to :order
after_save :set_order_status

enum status: { pending: 0, confirmed: 1, refunded: 2 }

def set_order_status 
  self.order.refunded! if self.refunded?
end
```

Comment: perfect thanks for updating ;)  the `self.save` was raising `stack level to deep`, but now it is what I expected :)

Comment: Welcome , please check my updated answer, if your issue is resolved you can accept this answer :)